# Removing password check in edit Profile

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

for a sf application i want to remove the password check from the edit profile form in FOSUserBundle.

Just removing the "current" field by overriding the profile form still causes the "Password invalid" validation message. This is caused by the ProfileFormHandler class from FOSUSerBundle by the following code:

```
 $this->form->setData(new CheckPassword($user));
```

So i overrided the form handler as well and replaced the above code with

```
 $this->form->setData($user);
```

So far this works and my form type is displayed and my form handler handles the form, but i get the following error

```
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form
```

Indeed the csrf token is not added to the form anymore. Frankly i don't know what i did wrong ;(

thx, ben

Here is the complete code of the form, the handler and the template:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ProfileFormType extends \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
{

    private $class;

    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
       $builder
           ->add('first_name')
            ->add('last_name')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('location','room13_geo_location')
            ->add('birthday','birthday')
            ->add('smoker')
            ->add('newsletter')
        ;


    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'balkanride_user_profile';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => $this->class,
            'intention'  => 'profile',
        );
    }
}
```

-

```
<?php


namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Model\CheckPassword;

class ProfileFormHandler
{
    protected $request;
    protected $userManager;
    protected $form;

    public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    public function process(UserInterface $user)
    {

        $this->form->setData($user);

        if ('POST' === $this->request->getMethod())
        {
            $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

            //var_dump($this->form->getErrors());
            //die();

            if ($this->form->isValid())
            {

                $this->onSuccess($user);

                return true;
            }

            // Reloads the user to reset its username. This is needed when the
            // username or password have been changed to avoid issues with the
            // security layer.
            $this->userManager->reloadUser($user);
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function onSuccess(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }
}
```

-

```
{% extends "ApplicationSonataUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}


{% block page_body %}

<section>

    <form id="ProfileForm" action="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_profile_edit">
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" value="{{ 'profile.edit.submit'|trans }}" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a href="{{path('fos_user_profile_show')}}" class="btn">{{ 'profile.edit.cancel'|trans }}</a>
            </div>

        </div>



    </form>

</section>

{% endblock page_body %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested way to fix this is to create a separate form to edit the fields that do not need password protection before they can be edited. Easiest and without hacks :)

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. The question was very old and the problem is not present any more... still I'm gonna mark your answer as correct for completeness ;)